# Rails 4. Set up comment editing functionality with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models: `User`, `Product` and `Comment`. The user can add, edit and delete comments to the product. I've successfully set up adding and deleting functionality and now I'm struggling with editing, for some reason, it caused me a number of difficulties.

My current code returns this error when I click on the `edit comment` link:

> NoMethodError at /products/800/comments/8/edit
>
> undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

---

Here's how my comment model looks like:

```
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  body       :text
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  user_id    :integer
#  product_id :integer

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  # validations ...
end
```

In `User` model I have `has_many :comments` and in `Product` - `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy`.

In my `routes.rb` file I have the following nested resources:

```
  resources :products, only: [:show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end
```

My `ProductsController` has the only method `show` and nothing else, and here's how it looks like:

```
  def show
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    photos = ProductsPhoto.where(product: product)
    case product.products_category.name
    when 'Violin'
      @product = [product, Violin.where(product: product).first, photos]
    when 'Guitar'
      @product = [product, Guitar.where(product: product).first, photos]
    when 'Saxophone'
      @product = [product, Saxophone.where(product: product).first, photos]
    when 'Piano'
      @product = [product, Piano.where(product: product).first, photos]
    end
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comments = Comment.where(product_id: product.id).order('created_at DESC')
  end
```

And now here's my `CommentsController`, which has `create`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy`:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @product, notice: 'Comment Created!'
    else
      redirect_to @product, notice: 'Something went wrong...'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
        format.html do
          redirect_to [@comment.product, @comment], notice: 'Comment Updated!'
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit', notice: 'Something went wrong...' }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy!
    redirect_to @product, notice: 'Comment Deleted!'
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

My `_form` view is located at `views/products/_form.html.erb` and looks like this:

```
  <%= simple_form_for([@product[0], @product[0].comments.build]) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= f.input :body, required: true, placeholder: 'Type in your comment...', input_html: { class: 'form-control'}, label: false %>
        <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
  <% end %>
```

And in the `views/products/show.html.erb` I render the partial of comments and there are the links for destroying and editing the comment, they look like this:

```
<%= link_to edit_product_comment_path(comment.product, comment) do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
<% end %>
<%= link_to [comment.product, comment], method: :delete do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
<% end %>
```

the delete link works fine and the edit link doesn't.

Maybe I've mistaken with routes, here're the routes for comments:

```
product_comments POST       /products/:product_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
edit_product_comment GET        /products/:product_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
product_comment PATCH      /products/:product_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
PUT        /products/:product_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
DELETE     /products/:product_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

In my `views/comments/edit.html.erb` I render the same form:

```
  <%= render 'products/form' %>
```

however, when I click on the edit link, I get the following error:

> NoMethodError at /products/800/comments/8/edit
>
> undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

at the very first line of the `_form.html.erb`.

---

I hope I've provided enough information to describe the problem.

So, could you please help me with resolving that issue with comments editing?

Comment: @Pavan this gave me the exact same error in the same place... :(

Comment: Have you tried debugging your `edit` action in the Comments controller to see if the product is being found?

Comment: @Nathan I'm not sure how should I debug this. I cannot access the `update` method, but I can debug `edit` and both `@product` and `@comment` variables there are being found correctly.

Comment: How have you debugged the edit action to know @product is being set?

Comment: both `@product` and `@comment` are being set. I used `byebug` at the end of the `edit` action

Comment: Ok, can you comment out the form on the view template and render the data in those variables? If yes, try pasting the form directly into the template without using the partial template. If that works, it may be that you need to pass the instance variables down to the partial using local variables.

Comment: As a sidenote to Nathan's help, I notice that in your form, you're building a comment, this means you'll never be able to edit the comment because it will  just create a new one.  better to call `= simple_form_for([@product, @comment]) do |f|` and in your product and comments controller do `@comment = @product.comments.build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too early this morning...

This is not correct  :

```
  <%= simple_form_for([@product, @product.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

Try :

```
 <%= simple_form_for [@comment.product_id, @comment],  url: product_comment_path(@comment.product_id, @comment)  do |f| %>
```

**Added section**

(All of this is assuming that we are working with a single @comment, not the @comments collection. Based on your comments about the delete working.)

To reply to your comment, yes, absolutely you do need separate forms for "new" versus "edit" action for your child table, comments.

Form "new" naming convention is comments/_form.html.erb, the "edit" form would be comments/_form_edit.html.erb,

I would open the "new" action form for comments...

```
<%= simple_form_for([:product, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

And the "edit" action...

```
<%= simple_form_for [@comment.product_id, @comment],  url: product_comment_path(@comment.product_id, @comment)  do |f| %>
```

Sorry I forgot the URL on the previous version, I have updated the code snippet above to reflect this change as well. Caveat: There may be other ways to construct this link, but this is how I have implemented the case of having a product (parent) with reviews/comments (many children).

**Nested attributes**

In further response to your comment, I believe some of what you're looking for could be achieved by using nested attributes in forms. This is another topic. I would get the new/edit form simple cases working and then add complexity.

Comment: If you give this a try, please let me know how it goes.

Comment: this gave me `undefined method comments_path`. 
Please, look at the updated code of my `_form.html.erb`, the `@product` varaible in `ProductsController` is the array in which the first element is the `Product` object. How should I change the current form to make the `edit` action work? Maybe I should have different forms for creating comment (as in `views/products/_form.html.erb`) and for editing (e.g. in `views/comments/_form.html.erb`)? because `@product` in `CommentsController` is a `Product` object and in `ProductsController` it is an array

Comment: Yes. I left something out. Sorry. Added section to answer.

Comment: I did as you said to do and the editing form actually worked!  But now when I click the submit button when editing the comment, I get the routing error for `products/:id/comments/:id`

Comment: Now I've changed the redirecting in `comments_controller` and everything works perfectly. Thank you for the extended explanation and the correct answer!